# How to change height of a ListView item?

Tags: android, android-listview

After clicking one of the ListView elements, I want to change the height of the ListView Item, but I can't do it.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        final ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.GoodsIcon);
        final View finalView = view;
        icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    finalView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, dpToPx(250)));
            }
        });
   return finalView;
    }
```

But if you change the code a little, the script works but changes the height of all ListView item.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, dpToPx(250)));
       return view;
        }
```

How to make the ListView item height change after clicking icon(ImageView).?

Answer (score 0):

You can use View.getChildAt(int idx) to get the specific view. You can only get the visible items tho (it starts from the first visible one, if you need to get the first visible item you can use  ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()).

For example:

```
View view = mListView.getChildAt(index - mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

if(v == null)
   return;

view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, dpToPx(250)));
```

Comment: It probably does, careful of overlapping variable names.

Comment: It didn't help either.